# UIWebView: Why does the request not time out when using a non-existant hostname?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

My situation is this:

- I have a `UIWebView` which makes a POST request to a URL where the hostname is provided by the user.
- When the hostname does not exist, I need to timeout so that I can alert the user to say that they should check the their settings.

What is happening:

I make a request like this:

```
NSString *theURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://%@%@", _hostname, LOGIN_PART_URL];
NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Username=%@&Password=%@", _username, _password];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:theURL] 
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval:_timeoutInSecs];



[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody: [body dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[web loadRequest:request];
```

When the hostname does not exist on the network, I do not get any timeout response.

I have implemented all delegate methods of `UIWebViewDelegate`, and I get the following called in order when I use a non-existent hostname:

1. `webView: shouldStartLoadWithRequest: navigationType:`

   - (returns true always for testing)
2. `webViewDidStartLoad`

And that's it - nothing after that.

I'm surprised that `webViewDidStartLoad` gets called, as this would suggest that it found the URL and thinks it can get data back from it. But it can't as the URL does not exist!

Am I doing something wrong here?

I have a workaround which I am going to implement, which uses an `NSTimer` to see if a response has been received within the timeout period. However, I am having issues with cancelling a request for a `UIWebView` - but that's a topic for my next SO question!

So my questions:

1. Is it correct for `webViewDidStartLoad` to be called on an invalid URL?
2. Should I be seeing a request timeout error returned, with the way I have setup my request?

Thanks in advance!!

Stretch :)

Comment: I tried your code (with my own nonexistent hostname) and webViewDidStartLoad got called followed by didFailLoadWithError:. No idea why the error method is not being called for you.

Comment: Thanks for trying it our, Mr Peckington. I'm now starting to think it's the way our routers are configured here, and maybe that's the problem, not the code. Will investigate more and post my findings.

Comment: Is there any redirection going on?

Answer (score 2):

Use delegate method

```
webView:didFailLoadWithError:
```

Get the error from it. If the error code is

```
-1000 - Bad Url
-1001 - Request timed out
-1003 - Cannot find host
-1004 - Cannot connect to host
-1005 - Network connection lost
-1006 - NSLookupFailed
```

By checking this you can alert the user about the error.

Comment: ah - that's my point - webview:didFailLoadWithError never gets called. The last thing that gets called is webViewDidStartLoad