# How to cancel a request made in a UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

Due to an [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628409/uiwebview-why-does-the-request-not-time-out-when-using-a-non-existant-hostname) where I can't get the `NSURLRequest` timeout to fire in my `UIWebView`, I am trying to use an `NSTimer` to check to see if I've got a response within a designated period. If I haven't, then I want to cancel the request and warn the user.

However: I'm unable to find a way to cancel a current request that has been made in a `UIWebView`.

How do you do it?

I have setup the request for the `UIWebView` as follows:

```
NSString *theURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://%@%@", _hostname, LOGIN_PART_URL];
NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Username=%@&Password=%@", _username, _password];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:theURL] 
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval:_timeoutInSecs];



[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody: [body dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[web loadRequest:request];
```

I can see that `NSURLConnection` has a cancel method, but there seems to be no equivalent for `UIWebView`.

What am I missing?

Thanks!
Stretch :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a `stopLoading` method in `UIWebView` class. Does it meet your needs?

Per [`UIWebView` Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stopLoading):

> **stopLoading**
>
> Stops the loading of any web content managed by the receiver.
>
> `- (void)stopLoading`
>
> Stops any content in the process of being loaded by the main frame or any of its children frames. Does nothing if no content is being loaded.

Comment: Thanks! I feel dumb for not having found that.. I was tied up with UIWebViewDelegate methods. Cheers :)